# Where can I find a database (sqlite, csv, etc) of Dungeons & Dragons Basic Set character and monster data?

Tags: monsters, osr, dnd-bx

I'm writing an engine for Dungeons & Dragons Basic Set (Red and Blue Box) First Edition (1E) in Python and would like to be able to read from an existing database of what is in the players and experts guide books.

I'm looking for all the numerical data and spell data for all the classes and monsters.

I figure that something like this exists, and after plenty of Google'ing, I've found some for later editions, but not for the older ones.

It's fine if it is in some other format, but I'd like to be able to make it into a local, offline database format (like SQLite).

Answer (score 4):

[Overview of D&D retro-clones](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/overview-of-dd-retro-clones)

Check out the retro clones on that link.  Most everything there was created while at least thinking of the legal aspects of what could be used without problems.  As a plus, the materials can generally be downloaded in several readable formats which you should be able to write a simple parser for.

- AD&D -> OSRIC
- D&D Red(Moldvay) -> Labyrinth Lord
- OD&D -> Swords and Wizardry (should work for D&D Blue(Holmes) as well)

Answer (score 0):

I found an xlsx file in a forum called Dragonsfoot created by SBLaxman: https://www.dragonsfoot.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=51196