# Is there any popular contemporary "classic" D&D material?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, dnd-becmi

I've played the gamut of D&D editions from 2e, 3e, 4e, and the classic BECMI system, and after a year long hiatus from 4th edition, I'm considering running some "classic" D&D again.

I'm aware of continued interest in first edition, but is there any ongoing interest and materials being published, or related or derived from BECMI? (In the manner of Pathfinder and Rules Cyclopedia).

Comment: See also the overview of all retro-clones at [Overview of D&D retro-clones](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1751)

Comment: This comment was the best answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a specific retro-clone geared towards BECMI gaming....it is called Dark Dungeons and it is a replication of the one-book D&D Rules Cyclopedia!  This would appear to be exactly what you are looking for: http://darkdungeonsblog.wordpress.com/

You might also look at games that replicate Basic D&D, such as [Labyrinth Lord](http://www.goblinoidgames.com/) or [BFRPG](http://www.basicfantasy.org/downloads.html)

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely.  There are a number of websites out there that still publish modules, monsters and content of classic D&D.  Most refer to it as OSR - Old School Role-playing.

Here are 2 sites to get you started:

- [Dragons Foot](http://www.dragonsfoot.org/): A lot of content here especially modules and creatures.
- [The Mad Irishman](http://www.mad-irishman.net/pub_dnd_1e.html): This site has great replicas of the original character and DM sheets.

Try these, I don't think you will be disappointed.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget there's also a free fanzine for Classic D&D called *[Encounter](http://www.encountermagazine.au2.com)*.

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial list of OSR publishers that support all varieties of older D&D (OD&D, B/X, BECMI, 1st AD&D mostly).

http://www.batintheattic.com/oldschoolsurvey.htm

The big three are [OSRIC](http://www.knights-n-knaves.com/osric/) (AD&D 1st), [Labyrinth](http://www.goblinoidgames.com/) Lords (B/X), and [Swords & Wizardry](http://www.swordsandwizardry.com/) (Original D&D)

Swords & Wizardry Core rules is the most used for a heavily house ruled campaign as it has all the foundation of D&D in a concise format. Dark Dungeons is a BECMI clone where Labyrinth Lord is the older Moldavy/Cook B/X Clone. The differences between of all these are of inches and the modules and supplements are highly compatible between all of them.