# Seeking a specific D&D retro-clone

Tags: osr, product-identification, retro-clones

I'm fairly sure this game exists, but I can't figure out for the life of me which one it is. I know it's not Darker Dungeons, Labyrinth Lord, or LotFP, because I just checked them before posting this.

It's a retro-clone of old D&D, Rules Cyclopedia type stuff (though perhaps without the whole depth of the RC). It has ascending AC, attack bonuses, and saves. It uses Fort, Reflex, and Will instead of the old Paralyze/Petrify set. Can't remember how it handled thief skills. Hit points and spells were much more OD&D than 3E.

I would *swear* that I saw this game and just can't come up with the name, but I'm open to the possibility that I just imagined it.

Comment: Relevant: [Overview of D&D retro-clones](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/overview-of-dd-retro-clones)

Comment: Are you sure about the Fort/Ref/Will saves? I was thinking Basic Fantasy RPG, but it has the classic five saves, but everything else.

There are other retro-clones out there with FRW saves, but I can't think of a well-known one off the top of my head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Dungeon Crawl Classics* game seems to fit the above criteria, although it cuts off at level 10 as opposed to the RC's 36.

It uses the RC's classes, including that of Dwarf/Elf/Halfling as self-contained classes as opposed to having racial mechanics.  Ascending AC, attack bonuses, saves, all check.  Fort, Reflex, Will saves - check.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is *Blood & Treasure* which fits roughly in the RC space but using the three fold save system.  It does a more AD&D1 style race/class mix with dual classing for humans (including half-orcs and half-elves) and multi-classing for other races.