# Need help on going DnD5 or DnD3.5/Pathfinder

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-3.5e

I have a cluster situation. I used to DM Advanced DnD a looooong time ago and with life I gave it up for other things. Well my kids want to play DnD and want me to DM.

My oldest son went to a books sale and bought me bunch of 3.5 books, a WoW RPG book, and a Pathfinder.

My middle son is playing DnD 5.0

The dilemma is which route? I played 3.5 and like the customizability and freedom 3.5 brings, on the other hand its a old system and I think Pathfinder still follows it but Wizards no longer supports.

On the other side there is the new 5.0 but I don't know much about it.

My friend wants to sell me his 4.0 but a lot of people said BAD JOO JOO.

So anyway, I was hoping someone could give me some insight on the differences and what they would recommend.

Thanks

Returning DM

Comment: There is a question on the differences, but the recommendations will vary with opinion and taste.  I'll try to find a link. (5e brought me back to the hobby after years off ... but that's just one experience). How old are your two children?  [This is related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/62688/22566).

Comment: [This Q&A may be helpful](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13212/22566), and it is related.  Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get an idea for how this Q&A site is different from a discussion forum.  This kind of question, a game recommendation, isn't a great fit for our particular format. (Nothing wrong with the question itself).  It may be better asked at a forum.  [We have some recommended forums here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566).

Comment: @Ifusaso (No. We don't do recommendations or anything resembling them. If the problem is what game to choose, it's fundamentally off topic regardless of how it's phrased or what kind of answers it could be given.)

Comment: CalicosJack, we can't give a recommendation — our site is not suited to that kind of question and such things are considered off topic — but we can help you with the part of the question wanting to know more about the games you're considering. We already have a question about an overview of the different D&Ds (including its Pathfinder sibling — which note, is still supported, just not by WotC). I've marked this as a duplicate of that, since if we removed the off-topic request for a recommendation, it's the same question, and we avoid duplication of answering work.

Comment: If you do need some help deciding, that's an understandable situation to be in even though *this* site can't help. For that sort of thing a traditional RPG discussion forum is a suitable tool for the job, and I would second looking at KorvinStarmast's final link to our curated list of RPG forum suggestions. That should give you some ideas about where on the Internet a recommendation question can get some useful feedback.