# Which edition(s) of D&D is the Caverns of Thracia (1979) compatible with?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures

I am interested in running an open table along the same lines described by [this Alexandrian post](http://thealexandrian.net/wordpress/1223/roleplaying-games/opening-your-game-table) and I want to use the original Judges Guild [*Caverns of Thracia*](http://judgesguild.org/product/).

I can find a compatible OSR game I'm sure (I want something that has a free PDF rulebook and super-quick character creation, to suit having casual players at an open table), but I need to know what edition of D&D I'm looking for a match with. What edition of D&D was *Caverns of Thracia* written for and is compatible with?

Comment: We can't recommend a game for you ([game-recommendation questions are off topic here](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited)), but we can certainly answer the question about what edition of D&D the *Caverns of Thracia* is for and let you go from there. I've edited the question to focus on that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*The Caverns of Thracia* is compatible with Original D&D, Holmes Basic, and AD&D First Edition. To the extent that AD&D Second Edition didn’t change much of the basics, it is also compatible with that, and the same is true of the later Basic/Expert/etc. and Rules Cyclopedia versions of D&D.

*Thracia* reads like a mashup of OD&D and Holmes Basic or AD&D, which is how many of us gamed at the time. For example, at least one encounter (the cleric Holoste from room 84) has their alignment given as Lawful Evil (LE). The [two-axis alignment system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignment_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)) was created for AD&D, though it first saw print in Holmes Basic. The OD&D and later D&D B/X series used the one-axis alignment of Lawful/Neutral/Chaotic.

*Thracia* was copyright 1979, by which point the AD&D [Monster Manual](https://www.acaeum.com/ddindexes/setpages/monster.html), [Players Handbook](https://www.acaeum.com/ddindexes/setpages/phb.html), and probably [Dungeon Masters Guide](https://www.acaeum.com/ddindexes/setpages/dmg.html) had been released (the Dungeon Masters Guide was also released in 1979). This was a time of transition. Dark Tower, released the same year, was [marketed as a supplement for AD&D](http://www.acaeum.com/jg/Item0088.html).

[According to Jaquays](http://www.dragonsfoot.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=59661#p1322584), part of the reason *Thracia* was marketed as for D&D is that *Thracia* used house rules, and the licensing requirements for D&D supplements were less strict than for AD&D supplements:

> Even Dark Tower got a bit of a reaming from TSR … I was including
>   house rules elements in my design of an AD&D product … which was
>   verboten. That’s partly why Caverns of Thracia ended up under the D&D
>   brand … I could be more loose with my interpretation of the rules.

But the actual adventure was written for the author’s own campaign, which [by then had transitioned to AD&D](http://www.dragonsfoot.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=106&t=59661&start=120#p1742153):

> Caverns of Thracia was originally intended to be an AD&D title, just
>   like Dark Tower… My local group had gone 1E AD&D by that point (as
>   much as we could).
>
> The jackal-headed “dogbrothers” in CoT were originally supposed to be
>   AD&D Jackalweres. As those were AD&D-only creatures, I had to recreate
>   them as something else (and I don’t think I could back port the
>   jackalweres … that wasn’t acceptable).

So it was written with a house-ruled AD&D in mind, and edited with OD&D in mind. It’ll be compatible with any rules set that is compatible with those, which covers most of the OSR rules sets and even second edition AD&D and B/X D&D up to the Rules Cyclopedia.

Comment: Wow, this is amazingly detailed. I come from times of strict rules and compatability so figuring out things from the times before is hard but mostly because of my own beliefs.

Answer (score 6):

According to [RPGGeek](https://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/46078/caverns-thracia), it was written for Original ("White Box") D&D.

There are [several retroclones available](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/overview-of-dd-retro-clones) that are more or less compatible with "White Box" rules. (Even BECMI or AD&D-1e are not *too* different.)

Comment: Thanks, I still find all this OSR pretty difficult to decipher. The white box information really helps!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen it run with OSRIC (an AD&D 1e retroclone) as well. Should be a pretty easy fit. [You can download the PDF for free here](https://osricrpg.com/get.php) so it's an easy get to check for compatibility and compare. I don't have personal experience or knowledge of it being run in other editions.

Good luck that's a fun module!

Comment: Hi rredmond! Welcome to the RPGSE! On the Stack Exchange, we like answers to be complete and free standing. You can read more about the unique way this site works by taking the [tour] and reading our [help]. The OP is asking which editions (plural) the module is compatible with and it's not clear from your answer if OSRIC is the only one that is compatible. If it is, can you clarify on this point? If it isn't, your answer would be improved if you could expand it to cite the other editions that are compatible. Again, welcome! :-)

Comment: Thank you and understood! I haven't really played any other editions, but now I notice the plural. :D I was worried that I hadn't cited any research and went and found the OSRIC pdf so that I had something to cite. Also it looks like I answered a years old question. Sigh. My only excuse is that I'm new here. I'll try and make it more complete and also be more careful about answering. I think I'll likely just tool around and check the place out more... much different than forums, that I am used to. Thank you Rykara!

Comment: Answering older questions is something we encourage! One never knows when somebody will come perusing through with the same question months or years later and we want the most accurate, complete information available for that person to reference. In fact, we have the Necromancer badge for this exact reason. I am looking forward to seeing more questions/answers from you on the exchange, especially since you seem to be familiar with some of the older editions of D&D!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [version of *Caverns of Thracia* adapted to D&D 3.5 on DriveThruRPG](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/1358/Caverns-Of-Thracia?it=1), if that helps. I remember seeing it there a few weeks back when I was looking for old modules to work into my campaign setting.

The original was way before my time, so I can't help there. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I also saw that module but it's recommended for players level 3+ which would make it very difficult to accept new players as they would have to learn a lot of the intricacies of player creation in 3.5e which is not simple. Maybe I will run that with my 3.5e group though.

Comment: Yea you would have to put a little work in scaling it back for your group. Hope you find what you need. Have fun

Comment: The linked product is no longer available.